# csv module in python 2.7

Tags: excel, csv

I am following the below example from official csv module documentation with my own csv file

https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html

```
import csv

with open('examplecsvfile.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
    csvfilereader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    for row in csvfilereader:
        print row
        print ','.join(row)
```

What is the difference between print row and print ','.join(row)

With print row I get the below output from my csv file:

```
['#', 'Old_Ref_Id', 'Ref_Id', 'Parent item', 'Category', 'Tags', 'Subject', 'Priority',     'Description']
```

With print ','.join(row) I get below:

```
#,Old_Ref_Id,Ref_Id,Parent item,Category,Tags,Subject,Priority,Description
```

why is first output in the form of a list with individual elements inside [] seperate by , while the second output looks like a text string?

I am very new to python. Any guidance would be helpful.

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reader assigns a list to the `row` variable, and when you print it you see it as a list.

The `'.'.join(row)` creates a string joining all the elements of the list adding the constant string `.` as separator.

See [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods) for details about `join` and other `String` methods.